# Writing numbered headings in Writer

Tags: libreoffice

In Libreoffice Writer, I am trying to make all my numbered headings in the following form:

```
1. First title
     1.1 Subtitle
     1.2 Subtitle
2. Second title
     2.1 Subtitle
     2.2 Subtitle
         2.2.1 Subsubtitle
```

I tried playing around with `Tools > Outline Numbering`, but the best I can only get one of the following:

```
1. First title
     1.1 Subtitle
     1.2 Subtitle
2. Second title
     1.3 Subtitle
     1.4 Subtitle
```

Or

```
1. First title
     1.1 Subtitle
     1.2 Subtitle
2. Second title
     1.2 Subtitle
     1.3 Subtitle
```

Is there any way for me to put the subheading's numbering as a function of the numbering of the heading above, like in the example on the top?

I am running a `.docx` file in **LibreOffice 4.0.3.3**.

**Edit:** I edited this question as per suggestions in the comments.

#### Problem solved:

It seems like the big problem was the following. All the headings in the original file had a correct format (i.e. `Heading 1, Heading 2, etc`). **However**, they had not been correctly converted to the "corresponding" `Heading 1, Heading 2, etc` that Libreoffice uses (Thanks @gertvdijk). Thus, followin the steps in the accepted answer gets the job done.

Thanks!

Comment: The example on the top is how it works out for me when using `Tools > Outline Numbering`. Are you sure you did not reset any counter? **I guess you have probably hit the "Reset numbering" or "Continue previous numbering" context menu item.** And are you applying the regular styles ("Heading 1", "Heading 2" etc.)?

Comment: I am applying the regular styles. I tried "Continuew previous numbering", but doing this for a huge document with a lot of styles is a lot of effort.
Also, I am now remembering that maybe it has to do with the type of document: this document is a `.docx` file

Comment: This looks like a LibreOffice bug and as such off topic.

Comment: Please add answers as answers. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question here - don't include it in questions. While editing your question, edit it to properly match the situation (editing an OOXML file, etc.).

Comment: Hi Sosi. Your remark about `tools/outline numbering...` is right. You should look into my edited answer again. I do think there are several ways of doing this.

Comment: Okies! Thanks guys!
@gertvdijk thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just

3. Hit <kbd>F11</kbd> which opens the styles and apply the styles to heading 1 to 3.
4. Put your cursor in one of the headings and hit `Format/Bullets and Numbering...` (**update**: and not `Tools/Outline Numbering...` as mentioned before) in the menu bar.
5. Then select the tab `outline` and choose the option `numeric with all sublevels` (see image)

[image]

In the position tab of 'Bullets and Numbering' you can choose... their position of course. If you want the typical indent you suggest, just click default in the three different levels.

Enjoy.

[image]

Comment: I have no tab `Outline` in the `Outline Numbering` window. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/4DRthHZ.png
Also, I am now remembering that maybe it has to do with the type of document: this document is a `.docx` file

Comment: I have updated my answer, see comments on your question.

Answer (score 4):

If you follow the answer of @don.joey, you will make the WHOLE YOUR DOCUMENT A NUMBERED LIST! Better avoid it! There are more natural native ways to number the headings. The `Tools -> Chapter (Outline) Numbering` is a much better way to go!

If you encounter some unexplainable problems sometimes you might need to reset the problematic heading style (change it to Default and back to Heading).